# Use Integrated Inted HD 4600 for X server and dedicated Nvidia GTX 970 for CUDA

Tags: 14.04, drivers, gpu, cuda

I have a brand new computer and I am planning on installing *Ubuntu 14.04 LTS* on it.

I will use it for calculations that is why it has the Cuda-enabled **Nvidia GTX 970** GPU.

I'd like to have this GPU dedicated for calculations, and keep the integrated **Intel HD 4600** for running the X Server (GUI).

Could you please advise me on the best way to perform the installation to avoid any conflicts?

Here is my plan, please let me know your thoughts!

1. Physically install the Nvidia GPU
2. Select the Intel IGP in the bios
3. Perform a full installation of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
4. Check that everything is working fine
5. Install CUDA following these instructions: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/, following the manual installation with the option --no-opengl-libs enabled.

Thanks in advance!